# Increase dynamic array size with a function; free error, invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a dynamic array and put five number, after there is another input which is how much I have to increase the array size.
When all input are ended I am going to increase the array size and put numbers inside.

everything works but free return me this error: "free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000..."

I think there are errors inside "extend" function

```
void extend(int *V, int n, int s)
{
    int *pt;
    pt = realloc(V, n*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    pt[5]=s;
    for(i=6;i<(5+n);i++)
        pt[i] = pt[i-1]*2;
}

int main()
{
    int *v;
    int n,i, sum;
    sum = 0;

    v = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        sum+=v[i];
    }   

    scanf("%d", &n);

    extend(v,n,sum);

    for(i=0;i<(5+n);i++)
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does not change the original variable `v`. It should be defined at least like

```
void extend(int **V, int n, int s)
{
    int *pt;
    pt = realloc(*V, n*sizeof(int));
    if ( pt )
    {
        int i;
        pt[5]=s;
        for(i=6; i < n; i++)
        pt[i] = pt[i-1]*2;
        *V = pt; 
    }
}
```

Or

```
int extend(int **V, int n, int s)
{
    int *pt;

    pt = realloc(*V, n*sizeof(int));
    int success = pt != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        int i;
        pt[5]=s;
        for(i=6; i < n; i++)
        pt[i] = pt[i-1]*2;
        *V = pt; 
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function should be called lije

```
extend( &v,n,sum);
```

Take into account that the function is unsafe because in general `n` can be less than or equal to 5. And this statement

```
for(i=6;i<(5+n);i++)
          ^^^^
```

can result in undefined behavior.

Or the function shall allocate n + 5 elements. For example

```
    pt = realloc(*V, ( n + 5 )*sizeof(int));
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Also the using of this magic number 5 is unclear and does not make sense.

Comment: I have an array of 5 elements, "n" is a number, extend function should add others "n" elements to the array with 5 elements.



For example: Array[5], n = 3 -> Array[8]

Comment: @user4789408 The function allocates n elements but in the loop there is used n + 5 elements.

Comment: @user4789408 If you want to extent to 8 elements, you must pass n=8 to your function, not n=3. `realloc()` gets the new size. Not the delta size.

Comment: I modified the code, now with "realloc(V, (5+n)*sizeof(int))" it should be ok?

Comment: @user4789408 It is a bad idea because now you force others to modify their answers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'll keep the original answer

Comment: addionally I would suggest to make `extend()` return whether or not `realloc()` was successful (return `pt` or 0/-1), because if it fails, the calling function must not try to fill any more array elements

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in function `extend`:

- You are allocating `pt` to a memory block of `n` entries
- You are attempting to access `pt` at indexes beyond `n-1`

More specifically, with:

```
pt = realloc(V, n*sizeof(int));
for (i=6; i<(5+n); i++)
    pt[i] = ...
```

You are performing illegal memory-access operations on:

- `pt[n]`
- `pt[n+1]`
- `pt[n+2]`
- `pt[n+3]`
- `pt[n+4]`

Comment: Your answer is correct, that solved the problem but now I would know why output was correct?

Comment: @user4789408: I don't understand "now I would know why output was correct"... Is that a question???

Comment: If I am performing illegal memory-access operation on pt[n], pt[n+1] why at the end of Main the output is correct?

Comment: This in undefined behaviour. And _undefined_ really means that anything can happen. Even printing your expected result could happen. Not every access to illegal memory location causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The realloc returns a pointer to the new memory block but you do not return that to the caller. Instead v in main, is the same v that was before the call but now invalid and which causes your error no doubt, easiest is to return pt instead:

```
int* extend(int *V, int n, int s)
{
    int *pt;
    pt = realloc(V, n*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    pt[5]=s;
    for(i=6;i<(5+n);i++)
    pt[i] = pt[i-1]*2;
    return pt;
}
...
v = extend(v,n,sum);
```

another thing that is not correct is your initialization of the new elements, n should contain the number of new elements **plus** any old since you want the allocated the block to be bigger. better to give old and new number of elements to it:

```
int* extend(int *V, int oldNumber, int newNumber, int s)
{
    int *pt = realloc(V, newNumber*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    if (pt==NULL) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory\n");
      return V;
    }
    pt[oldNumber]=s;
    // now you can initialize the rest of the array
    for(i=oldNumber+1;i<newNumber;i++) 
      pt[i] = pt[i-1]*2;
    return pt;
}
...
v = extend(v,5,n,sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Grow an array like this

```
  int capacity = 10; // don't start off as tiny
  ENTRY *array = malloc(capacity * sizeof(ENTRY));
  int N = 0;   //number of entries.
```

To add

```
   int addentry(ENTRY *entry)
   {
      ENTRY *temp;

      if(N >= capacity)
      {
          temp = realloc(array, (capacity + capacity/2) * sizeof(ENTRY));
          if(!temp)
            goto out_of_memory;
          array = temp;
          capacity = capacity + capacity/2;
      }
      array[N] = *entry;
      N++;
      return 0;
    out_of_memory:
        //always a problem, maybe terminate program here
        // as it is, just shunt up
        return -1;
   }
```

You need the temp because realloc returns 0 on failure but keeps
the argument intact, so you need to keep array to destroy it
gracefully. Grow by about 1.5, doubling is too aggressive and
reallocating on every call is too expensive.